# NIM game - re-running the game

Tags: python

I have to do a small game called NIM. The game is a human vs. computer game where each player removes a number of straws (1,2 or 3) and the player who removes the last straw looses. I got the game to work properly but the problem is that it doesn't want to re-run if the player wants to play again. Any help would be apprecieted. :)

```
import random
print("""************ NIM GAME   ***********
************ Game Start ***********
************ The rules  ***********
-----------------------------------------------------
You need to remove from 1 to 3 straws from the pile.
The player that removes the final straw is the loser.
-----------------------------------------------------""")

player1=str(input("Enter your name. "))
player2="Computer"
howMany=0
gameover=False
strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)

if (strawsNumber%4)==1:
    strawsNumber+=1

def removingStrawsComputer():
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    global strawsNumber
    while removedNumber>strawsNumber:
    removedNumber=random.randint(1,3)
    strawsNumber-=removedNumber
    return strawsNumber

def removingStrawsHuman():
    global strawsNumber
    strawsNumber-=howMany
    return strawsNumber

def humanLegalMove():
    global howMany
    legalMove=False
    while not legalMove:
        print("It's your turn, ",player1)
        howMany=int(input("How many straws do you want to remove?(from 1 to 3) "))
        if  howMany>3 or howMany<1:
            print("Enter a number between 1 and 3.")
        else:
            legalMove=True
    while howMany>strawsNumber:
        print("The entered number is greater than a number of straws remained.")
        howMany=int(input("How many straws do you want to remove?"))
    return howMany

def checkWinner(player):
    if strawsNumber==0:
        print(player," wins.")
        global gameover
        gameover=True
        return gameover

def resetGameover():
    global gameover
    gameover=False
    return gameover

def game():
    while gameover==False:
        print("It's ",player2,"turn. The number of straws left: ",removingStrawsComputer())
        checkWinner(player1)
        if gameover==True:
            break
        humanLegalMove()        
        print("The number of straws left: ",removingStrawsHuman())
        checkWinner(player2)

def playAgain():
    answer=input("Do you want to play again?(y/n)")
    resetGameover()
    while answer=="y":
        game()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing the game")

game()
playAgain()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reset the number of straws at the start of each game. After `def game():`, you should insert:

```
global strawsNumber
strawsNumber=random.randint(10,20)
```

Note: you also need to put `answer=input("Do you want to play again?(y/n)")` at the end of your `while answer=="y":` loop. This will ask the user for a replay every time, instead of just after the first game.